# Blur circle area in RGB image using MATLAB

Tags: matlab, filter, blur

Is there any way to blur some region in RGB image using `imfilter` function? I know there is function like `roifilt2` to filter selected region in image. But this is just works for grayscale image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just use `roifilt2` on each individual image layer. Layer 1=red,2=green,3=blue

```
filtered_im = zeros(size(orig_im));
filtered_im(:,:,1) = roifilt2(your_filter, orig_im(:,:,1), your_roi);
filtered_im(:,:,2) = roifilt2(your_filter, orig_im(:,:,2), your_roi);
filtered_im(:,:,3) = roifilt2(your_filter, orig_im(:,:,3), your_roi);
```